# Result of Trying to Insert an Element Before Itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

When I have the HTML:

```
<div>
    <p id="first">First paragraph!</p>
    <p id="second">Second paragraph!</p>
</div>
```

And I run the script:

```
var second = $('#second');
$('#second').insertBefore(second);
```

The result is:

```
<div>
    <p id="first">First paragraph!</p>
</div>
```

I know the code is nonsensical but I'm writing code where it's possible that the item I'm inserting is equal to the item I'm inserting before.

Can someone help me understand why I got the results above? What happened to `#second`?

Comment: As an aside: it might be wise to just ignore the insert if the elements are the same.

Comment: @Matchu: Yes, I realized that. Just trying to get a better understand of what is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [W3C DOM 3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727):

> Note: Inserting a node before itself is implementation dependent.

When inserting a node, if it's already in the DOM it is first removed. So you are then trying to insert it before a node (itself) that is no longer in the DOM. You should test if the two nodes are the same and if they are, don't do the insert.

#### Edit

A plain js function to do the above is:

```
function doInsert(insertNode, beforeNode) {
  if (insertNode != beforeNode) {
    beforeNode.parentNode.insertBefore(insertNode, beforeNode);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Though the spec is unclear on what *should* happen, my guess is:

1. `#second` is first removed from the DOM so that it can be inserted somewhere else.
2. Now we try to insert it before `#second`, but, since `#second` isn't in the DOM anymore, it has no place to go.

Comment: I haven't looked, but I would imagine that the spec requires a DOM Exception. Or maybe not.

Comment: I had considered that, but it seemed kind of strange that the element would be pulled before it's figured out where it's going. Thanks.